# CloudFormation: Reference and use Parameters in inline python code for custom resource?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, parameters, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

//This is inside one cloudformation template

//These are the parameters, from here i want to use the OpsBucketname

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform:
  - AWS::LanguageExtensions
  - AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Parameters:
  DeploymentHash:
    Type: String
    Description: sample description
  Stage:
    Type: String
    Description: sample description
  OpsBucketName:
    Type: String
```

//These are the resources where I want to use the parameter, on the lambda function, code: zipfile: - on the lambda_handler

```
Resources:
  CognitoUiCustomizationLambdaRole:
  Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
   // ...
  CognitoSetUiCustomizationLambda:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
```

```
          import boto3
          import logging

          logger = logging.getLogger()
          client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
          s3 = boto3.client('s3')

          def lambda_handler(event, context):
              logo = s3.get_object(Bucket="${OpsBucketName}",            Key="${BlockPrefix}/assets/frontend/assets/images/logo.png") 

              // other codes here not related to questions ...
```

```
      Description: Lambda for custom resource to customize the cognito login page
      FunctionName: !Sub "CognitoLoginCustomization-${NamingSuffix}"
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.9
      Timeout: 10
      Role: !GetAtt CognitoUiCustomizationLambdaRole.Arn
```

My main purpose here is to get the bucket name from the parameters and then use it to get the logo from that bucket and use that logo on the cognito_idp.setUiCustomization() function to set a custom cognito login page.

Inside my function lambda_handler im using the OpsBucketName using the syntax ${OpsBucketName}
but in my cloudwatch logs,the error is it is empty but Im sure it has a value as the other resources not using a custom resource is successfully created and has successfully used that bucket name.

Is my syntax of using that parameter here correct? I cant find a sample on the internet the same with my problem.
Thank you very much.

I tried searching on the documentation for this scenario but i did not see one. Im expecting to see a sample where the parameters are used on the lambda function, Code: ZipFile using python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you can achieve it directly from the Parameters, but then you can make use of the `Environment` variables inside your inline lambda function by referring to the `Parameters` you've defined in the Cloudformation template.

First we need to create environment variables that point to your `Parameters`:

```
LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Environment:
        Variables:
          DeploymentHash: !Ref DeploymentHash
          Stage: !Ref Stage
          OpsBucketName: !Ref OpsBucketName
```

and then extract these environment variables within your inline code

```
# extracting the env variables first
deploymentHash = os.environ.get('DeploymentHash')
stage = os.environ.get('Stage')
opsbucketname = os.environ.get('OpsBucketName')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # your code
```

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. That will solve my problem. That was fast. I appreciate it.